# Новый подход к геймификации

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, синонимы, неологизмы

Томский университет занимается исследованием мифов в контексте видеоигр. ТПУ получил президентский грант ([Томские ученые тратят президентский грант на изучение «Ведьмака» | tayga.info](http://tayga.info/139242)).

Как можно преобразовать слово *геймификация* или Чем его заменить?

Answer (score 2):

Есть термин **геймология** ― наука о компьютерных играх, а **геймификация** ― это придание игрового характера какой-либо деятельности, например образовательной. Оба термина уже существуют, нет смысла их менять.

http://samlib.ru/b/bondarewa_o_i/prikladnajagejmologija.shtml

https://moluch.ru/archive/113/28806/

Comment: Я о «новом подходе», актуальном для этого проекта. Встроенное ключевое «миф» в уже существующем слове затерялось. Как его проявить?

Comment: Я не уверена, что слово "миф"  надо как-то проявлять. Геймификация - общее название, а  мифы - частная тема, в которой можно выявить новые приемы и закономерности геймификации.

Comment: Понятно. Не уверена — тоже ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то геймификация = гейм+ификация (Game - игра, Gamer - игрок), ификация —процесс, действие.

Значит, геймификация — процесс применения игровых элементов и механизмов в неигровом контексте, или формирование игрового мышления.

Можно заменить — игрофикация (игрофокация)

ТПУ, видимо, действительно создал неологизм, использовав  аппликацию, наложение морфем, что наблюдается, в частности, в слове тарификация (тар/иф + иф/икация).А они наложили второй корень миф:

Гей/м + миф + иф/икация — игровой процесс с использованием мифов (использование мифов в играх) Заменить можно термином **"мифологемы в видеоиграх"**(мифологизация игр) или  ещё одним неологизмом — мифогеймификация.

Comment: Согласен с изложенным. Использование слова слегка не по назначению чревато. Я бы добавил всего лишь букву: гейммификация.

Comment: Согласна, только смысл этого слова всё равно будет "не по назначению", ведь получится гейм+мификация - превращение игры в миф, какое - то непонятное, обратное значение.

Comment: Но двусмысленности не стало, и на язык уже ничто неприличное не просится.